# How to sort a list of dictionaries by one of it value, but printing the other key's value?

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib

I'm a python newbie, but I'm trying to iterate through the following list of dicts:

```
MonthEngList = [{'MonthNumber': 1, 'MonthName': 'January'}, 
{'MonthNumber': 2, 'MonthName': 'February'}, {'MonthNumber': 3, 'MonthName': 'March'}, 
{'MonthNumber': 4, 'MonthName': 'April'}, {'MonthNumber': 5, 'MonthName': 'May'}, 
{'MonthNumber': 6, 'MonthName': 'June'}, {'MonthNumber': 7, 'MonthName': 'July'}, 
{'MonthNumber': 8, 'MonthName': 'August'}, {'MonthNumber': 9, 'MonthName': 'September'}, 
{'MonthNumber': 10, 'MonthName': 'October'}, {'MonthNumber': 11, 'MonthName': 'November'}, 
{'MonthNumber': 12, 'MonthName': 'December'}]
```

I'm using that as the labels to a plot with ticker in matplotlib, but somehow the months get meddled up. 
I did figure out that I should use sorted() ..  but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Here is what I did:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
pos_list_mm = np.arange(1,12)

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator((pos_list_mm)))

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(  ticker.FixedFormatter( 
sorted(MonthEngList,key=MonthEngList('MonthName') ) )  )

plt.show() 
plt.draw()
```

yielding:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vectorialbox_with_save.py", line 135, in <module>
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(  ticker.FixedFormatter( sorted(MonthEngList,key=MonthEngList('MonthName') ) )  )
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Any hint as to how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling sorted(), the function is expecting MonthEngList to be a dictionary.  MonthEngList is actually a list of dictionaries.  Try running MonthEngList('MonthName') alone and you would get the same list is not a  callable object error.

Try putting your months in a dictionary that looks like this:

```
MonthEngList = {'MonthName':[Jan,...,Dec],'MonthNum':[1,...12]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution as far as sorting the list of dictionaries is concerned:

```
lst=map(lambda x:x.items(),MonthEngList)
```

this code converts list of dictionaries into list of lists of tuples(key,value pairs in dictionary), so this will result in:

```
 lst=[[('MonthNumber', 1), ('MonthName', 'January')], [('MonthNumber', 2), ('MonthName', 'February')], [('MonthNumber', 3), ('MonthName', 'March')], [('MonthNumber', 4), ('MonthName', 'April')], [('MonthNumber', 5), ('MonthName', 'May')], [('MonthNumber', 6), ('MonthName', 'June')], [('MonthNumber', 7), ('MonthName', 'July')], [('MonthNumber', 8), ('MonthName', 'August')], [('MonthNumber', 9), ('MonthName', 'September')], [('MonthNumber', 10), ('MonthName', 'October')], [('MonthNumber', 11), ('MonthName', 'November')], [('MonthNumber', 12), ('MonthName', 'December')]]
```

Next sort the list of lists based on the second element of the second tuple of each list, which is done by:

```
y=sorted(lst,key=lambda x:x[1][1])
```

At last extract the second element of first tuple from each list in the sorted result, which is achieved by following code:

```
desired_list= map(lambda x:x[0][1],y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just pass in the months since they are already in sorted order (i.e.

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(
    [x['MonthName'] for x in MonthEngList]))
```

where we use a list comprehension to extract just the `MonthName` from each list entry.  If for some reason you did need to sort the months, you could use

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(
    [x['MonthName'] for x in sorted(MonthEngList, key=lambda y: y['MonthNumber'])]))
```

where again we use a list comprehension just to get the month names, but we first sort the list based on the `MonthNumber` of each list entry.